# What MYSQL data type should I use to store 64-bit double precision?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, floating-point, double

I want to store [traditional 64-bit floating points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) but I am confused with all the [various](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html) [options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html) I have in MYSQL e.g. `FLOAT(M,D)`, `REAL(M,D)`, `DOUBLE(M,D)`, `FLOAT`, `DOUBLE PRECISION(M,D)`, `REAL`, `DOUBLE`, `DECIMAL(M,D)` and `NUMERIC`. Which one is best suited to store double precision floating point formats? If I need to specify `M` or `D`, what should I specify?

Answer (score 3):

To store a 64 bit (8 byte) floating point number, use `DOUBLE PRECISION` or its alias/equivalent `DOUBLE`.  They are the same.  `FLOAT` is a single-precision 32-bit number, and `REAL` might be either one, depending on server config, so stay away from that one.

Don't specify the (M,D) values unless you have a reason to, because then you're not getting a "traditional" 64-bit number.

Standard disclaimer, don't use any of these -- use `DECIMAL` instead -- unless you fully understand the inherent imprecision of floating point number storage and operations.  Money values, for example, are almost always candidates for a `DECIMAL` column.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-types.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html